# How stop PivotTable re-calculation after I change measure via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA macros, I have to change measure formulas in data model in Excel.
The code snipped which changes formula of every measure:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Model.ModelMeasures(1).Formula = textOfNewMeasureFormula
```

Right after the macros changes every particular measure, Excel starts re-calulating the PivotTable. In case of big data it may take a long time and so inconvenient. It would be great to change all the measure needed and launch re-calculation after all that changes.
But I cannot find a solution for that.

This code doesn't work, because it's about updating data:

```
activeSheet.PivotTables(1).ManualUpdate = true
```

It doesn't have any effect on the calculation after formula measure change.

This doesn't help either, because it's about formulas in Excel Sheets:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Just in case - I didn't check

```
Application.Visible = false
```

because it is anyway not acceptable for my case.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` doesn't do anything, correct?

Comment: Yes, PivotTable recalculates regardless of this setting, so this is not the solution, unfortunately. Sorry not mentioing this in the question

Answer (score 0):

In the settings (File->Options->Formula), there is an option for formula calculation. If you change it to "manual", it will disable automatic calculations. However, you need to control the update manually, you can use "F9" button for it.
If you want to control this setting in macro, you can use:

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

to turn calulation method to manual

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

to turn the calculation method to automatic.

Comment: PivotTable recalculates regardless of this setting, so this is not the solution, unfortunately. Sorry not mentioning this in the question